# Grails angularjs phoneCat example shows blank index.gsp page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, grails

I have created a grails application following the angularjs PhoneCat tutorial here (http://www.inoneo.com/en/blog/14/grails/angular-phonecat-tutorial-using-a-grails-backend). When I tried running the app, the index page is coming out blank. I have pasted below the index.gsp content and what i was able to get when i viewed the source of what is being displayed

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<r:require module="angular"/>
<r:layoutResources/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="view-container" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
</div>
<r:layoutResources/>
</body>

</html>

===============
Source
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link href="/dropstore/static/bundle-bundle_angular_head.css"     

type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />



</head>

<body>
<div class="view-container" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
</div>
<script src="/dropstore/static/bundle-bundle_angular_defer.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
========
```

I am also getting the error that is as follows in my firefox console
 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
 I have searched through multiple similar topics but still unable to figure out the
 problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am still battling with this issue, anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, static resources are located under `/GrailsAngularPhonecat/` like:

`/GrailsAngularPhonecat/static/bundle-bundle_angular_defer.js"`

Or in your example it's:

`/dropstore/static/bundle-bundle_angular_defer.js`

Something is wrong with the path to static resources, try checking out the project again.

This example was made using Grails 2.3.7 https://grails.org/download, you'll have to run the same version to launch it.

To make it easier to try the example, I've [added a WAR](https://github.com/BenoitWickramarachi/grails-angular-phonecat/tree/master/release) so you can deploy it to an application server (like Tomcat).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try it out and let you know if it works.

Comment: I changed the version of my grails to 2.4.4 then i changed BuildConfig.groovy to have the latest plugins required and then it works.